# How to build this product with google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to build an exact replica of a website with a different landmark to point towards.

Could you please tell me what I should learn in order to do it please ?

So far, I've created this and don't know what to do next :

https://jsfiddle.net/hasnain721/01v7s2m4/6/

I am a very basic coder btw!

Thanks in advance!

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.3478, -6.2597),
   zoom: 16,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 });

 var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   map: map
 });
 // Try HTML5 geolocation.
 if (navigator.geolocation) {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
       var pos = {
         lat: position.coords.latitude,
         lng: position.coords.longitude
       };
       //infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
       // infoWindow.setContent('<b>You are here.</b><br><b>Lat:</b> '+position.coords.latitude+'<br><b>Lon:</b> '+position.coords.longitude);  
       map.setCenter(pos);
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: pos,
         map: map,
         title: String(pos.lat) + ", " + String(pos.lng),
       });

       //draws out the path from current location to landmark
       var flightPlanCoordinates = [{
           lat: position.coords.latitude,
           lng: position.coords.longitude
         },
         {
           lat: 21.4224779,
           lng: 39.8251832
         }
       ];
       var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
         path: flightPlanCoordinates,
         geodesic: true,
         strokeColor: '#FF0000',
         strokeOpacity: 1.0,
         strokeWeight: 2
       });
       flightPath.setMap(map);

       //draws out the path from current location to landmark


     },

     function() {
       handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
     });


 } else {
   // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
   handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the coordinates of the "flightPlanCoordinates" variable.

sample pointing at the Statue of Liberty :

```
  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude},
    {lat: 40.689249, lng: -74.0445}
  ];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Waren. I have the destination set correctly to what I want. The map is able to get current location, destination location and draw a line beteeen the two. My question is, what do I do next to make it like https://qiblafinder.withgoogle.com/intl/en/ ? I have to use the compass in some way to point towards the destination. Thanks !!